# DuplicateRestPathException in GAE while generating endpoint library

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm building backend with JAVA Google App Engine. I've created 3 api methods, all very similar.

Definitions goes like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getGamesOffThePodium")
    public CollectionResponse<MGameResult> getGamesOffThePodium(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
}

@ApiMethod(name = "getGamesWon")
    public CollectionResponse<MGameResult> getGamesWon(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
    }

@ApiMethod(name = "getGamesUnsolved")
    public CollectionResponse<MGameResult> getGamesUnsolved(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
}
```

ANd here is the exception Eclipse gives me when I'm trying to generate cloud enpoint client library:

[image]

Why is that? Can't I have 3 methods returning collection of the same objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have multiple objects returning same object. You need to add 'path' attribute in annotation.

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getGamesOffThePodium", path = "get_games_off_the_podium")
    public CollectionResponse<MGameResult> getGamesOffThePodium(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
}

@ApiMethod(name = "getGamesWon", path = "get_games_won")
    public CollectionResponse<MGameResult> getGamesWon(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
    }

@ApiMethod(name = "getGamesUnsolved", path = "get_games_unsolved")
    public CollectionResponse<MGameResult> getGamesUnsolved(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {
}
```